# Composite trapezoidal rule and Simpson rule question?

Tags: numerical-methods

We have the following integral $$\int_{1}^{3} \frac x{x^2+4}\; dx$$  and $n=6$. I have to approximate it using composite trapezoidal rule and then composite simpson rule.

Using trapezoidal rule:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\; dx = \frac h2 \left[f(a)+2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x_j)+f(b)\right]-\frac{b-a}{12}h^2f''(\mu)$$

where $h=\frac{3-1}6=1/3$.

Here is my solution for composite trapezoidal rule and error formula:

$$
h=\frac{b-a}n=\frac{3-1}6=\frac13 \\
\int_a^bf(x)\;dx = \frac h2 \left[f(a)+2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x_1)+f(b)\right]
$$

$$\begin{array}{c|l}
x & y \\
\hline
1 & 0.2 \\
\frac43 & 0.2343 \\
\frac53 & 0.2466 \\
2 & 0.25 \\
\frac73 & 0.2470 \\
\frac83 & 0.2400 \\
3 & 0.2307
\end{array}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^3\frac x{x^2+4}\;dx & = \frac16[0.2+0.2307+2(0.2343+0.2466+0.25+0.2470+0.24)] \\
& = 0.48065
\end{align}
$$

We see that $n=2$.

$$\begin{align}
E & =-\frac{b-a}{12}\cdot h^2f''(n) \\
& =-\frac2{12}\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^2\cdot\frac{2n\left(n^2-12\right)}{\left(n^2+n\right)^3}
\end{align}$$

Here $n=2$.

Comment: To approximate the integral, you usually don't have to write down the error term. On the other hand you haven't used that $n = 6$. So, this is not correct.

Comment: Composite it is.

Comment: @Amzoti I solved this for the composite trapezoidal rule and I also found the error.Is this correct? 
http://i.imgur.com/OsmPVS5.jpg

Comment: Thank you.Beside that,does it look alright?

Comment: I checked it,it is correct.